# Replace fields with values of other fields in the same line

Tags: awk, gawk, nawk

I have this kind of input:

```
rs10000004 C T 4 rs10000004 0 75625312 C C C C T 0 C T 
rs10000005 G A 4 rs10000005 0 75625355 G 0 A A A G A A
```

I want to substitute columns from 8 to end by "A" if the value in the column is identical to the 2nd field $2 or "B" if the value is identical to the third field $3. Else, the value is printed as it is (Zero values are expected in some columns)

Expected output

```
rs10000004 C T 4 rs10000004 0 75625312 A A A A B 0 A B 
rs10000005 G A 4 rs10000005 0 75625355 A 0 B B B A B B
```

I tried the following but it doesn't give me any results just empty lines. Improving my code is better for me than to show me a new solution using something other than awk

```
cat input | awk '{ for(i=8; i<=NF; i++) { if($i == $2) $i="A"; else if($i == $3) $i="B"; else $i == 0; } print $i }'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code** :

```
awk '
{
    for (i=8; i<=NF; i++) {
       if ($i == $2) {
           $i = "A";
       }
       else {
           if ($i == $3) {
               $i = "B";
           }
           else {
               $i = 0;
           }
       }
    }
    print;        
}' input
```

Or shorter :

```
awk '
{
    for (i=8; i<=NF; i++) {
       if ($i == $2)
           $i="A";
       else
           if ($i == $3)
               $i="B";
           else
               $i = 0;
    }
}
1' input
```

**Output** :

```
rs10000004 C T 4 rs10000004 0 75625312 A A A A B 0 A B 
rs10000005 G A 4 rs10000005 0 75625355 A 0 B B B A B B
```

Comment: Change the loop to start at `i=8` and remove the if statement.

Comment: ok so it works but I did a mistake which you might also have it which is after the last else { $i =0 } not $i == 0 
right ?

Comment: It can be even shorter, using the ternary operator: `awk '{for(i=8;i<=NF;i++) $i = ($i==$2) ? "A" : ($i==$3) ? "B" : 0}1' input`